# array_unique - php - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, array-unique

```
$skillsarray = ["php","java","ios","php","php","php","php","java","java","ios"];

$cityarray = ["Chennai","Theni","Theni","Mumbai","Chennai","Theni","Chennai","Hyderabad","Theni","Madurai"];
```

If I used `array_unique` for `$skillsarray`, getting result as

> ["php","java","ios"]

If I used `array_unique` for `$cityarray`,  getting result as

> {"0":"Chennai","1":"Theni","3":"Mumbai","7":"Hyderabad","9":"Madurai"}

Can anyone explain why the `array_unique($cityarray)` is producing dictionary result?

Comment: For both of the cases `array_unique` will return an `array` with unique values.

Comment: `array_unique` will return neither of these particular formats. You're omitting half the question…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_unique find first unique values from the array with id and that is the reason $cityarry is different from $skillarray. Please check image that will easy to understand...:)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFLoF.png)